# Cakephp 3 - Loading images externally from Cakephp server

Tags: cakephp

This is a fundamental issue, I know its probably do to with Cakephp routing but I need to be sure of the best practice method to do this.

I have 2 websites on 2 different servers / domains talking. Basically Website A on a different server needs to load an image stored on a Website B which is a Cakephp application. Both are on different domains / servers.

If Website A tries to load the image using the absolute path, which is for example: 
    www.website-b.com/img/image.png
This doesn't work (and i suspect its to do with the Cakephp routing on website-b).

Whats the best way to implement this (routing-wise or not) to allow this to happen?

On a side note, i notice loading image.png results in nothing, but loading image.jpg results in "IMGController" not found, which was expected. Not sure why the error doesn't pop up for png.

Comment: If `www.website-b.com/img/image.png` doesn't work, you've either changed the default routing or the image doesn't exist.

Comment: If the image exists in `webroot/img`, based on default url rewriting rules it should be served by web server itself and request would not be routed to cake app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because my image, although there in the Website-b filesystem, was 0kb in size. I was confused initially when loading Website-A, the network monitor didn't show any outgoing http request for the image as well. Anyways, the 0kb images was caused by another issue. Thanks all.